# ADX with different DI+ Di- parameters

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am trying to write an ADX indicator in pine script 5 with different DiPlus and DiMinus parameters.
eg. DiPlus = 14 and DiMinus = 9
Can it be done ?

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="Directional Movement Index", shorttitle="DMI", format=format.price, precision=4)
th = input(20)
lenP = input.int(12, minval=1, title="DI Plus Length")
lenM = input.int(9, minval=1, title="DI Minus Length")
lensig = input.int(14, title="ADX Smoothing", minval=1, maxval=50)
[diplus, diminus, adx] = ta.dmi(lenP, lensig)
hline(th, color=color.white)
plot(adx, color=color.red, title="ADX",linewidth = 2)
plot(diplus, color=color.blue, title="+DI")
plot(diminus, color=color.orange, title="-DI")
```